# Convert JSON /Date(1238626800000)/ to Unix Timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my code I get JSON response as `/Date(1238626800000)/`.

I want to convert this object to Unix Timestamp. So I would like to know that whether is there any default javascript or jquery method which can convert it to Unix Timestamp ?

So My Input Date is: `/Date(1238626800000)/` and 
Output I want is: `1238626800000`

I can do it with `RegEx` but this is last option if no default method available

Comment: yes, RegExp is the cleanest answer `new Date(input.replace(/\D+/g, '')*1)`

Answer (score 2):

No need to use regex here. Just [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) out the timestamp:

```
if (value.startsWith("/Date(") && value.endsWith(")/"))
    return new Date(Number(value.slice(6, -2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
var input = '/Date(1238626800000)/';
var re = /Date\(([0-9]*)\)/;
var ret = re.exec(a);
if(ret) {
    input = ret[1];
}
```